# How to set custom expiry to service-to-service authentication token in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-authentication, google-cloud-run

I am using the following curl method to generate the token. But this always return a token which is valid only for 60 mins. I want to increase the expiry of this token (up to 6 hours) using the below method. How can I achieve this?

```
curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/identity?audience=[AUDIENCE]&format=full&licenses=TRUE" \
 -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't generate a short lived credential from the metadata server. You need to query the Service account credential API. The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-short-lived-service-account-credentials) explains how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on several items:

1. Is your project part of an ORG?

If no, the answer is you cannot. If yes, modify the constraint **constraints/iam.allowServiceAccountCredentialLifetimeExtension** Google will fail token create requests for longer than 1 hour without this constraint. Then review the other items in this list.

2. Are you calling a Google API with the Identity Token?

If yes, the answer is you cannot. Google APIs will reject all tokens with an expiration of more than 1 hour.

3. Can you create/deploy a service account JSON key file to the instance?

The metadata service cannot be modified. The tokens are preset for one hour. You can use a service account to create OAuth tokens (Access and Identity) valid for up to 12 hours. Refer to item #1 and the link below. On my website, I have articles on how to create OAuth Tokens from service accounts.

4. Do you have a requirement to only use a Google SDK?

If yes, then the answer is you cannot. You must write code that creates a JWT with a custom payload, sign the JWT using the service account's private key and finally exchange the signed JWT for an OAuth Identity Token. The exchange occurs by calling a Google endpoint.

5. Are you using the Identity Token to call a service protected by IAP?

For this case, I do not know the answer. I have not attempted to use OAuth tokens with a longer expiration.

[Generating an OAuth 2.0 access token](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-short-lived-service-account-credentials#sa-credentials-oauth)

Comment: Thanks for this detail info. Following are my answer to your suggestion:
1. Yes, belongs to an organization - so applying this permission only sort out my issue?

Comment: That depends on the other question in my answer. Do not need to answer them here. My answer is a checklist for you to determine your strategy.

Comment: Ahh, I misunderstood at the first point. I will go through the checklist again. Many thanks.